# Twitter authentication for Sencha Touch mobile applications/javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I seek community's advice on twitter authentication and getting list of followers for Sencha Touch apps or javascript in general. I'm creating a mobile app for Android and iOS with Sencha Touch. I need to integrate twitter in the app and use it's login mechanism to authenticate the user and fetch logged-in user's followers from twitter side. I've gone through few examples which are using old technique which is depreciated now and twitter doesn't support authentication through javascript for some security issues.
Could someone please suggest any solution for twitter authentication through Sencha Touch app or javascript? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: my impression is that you need to use your own server because as you said they do not support javascript only authentication.

Comment: Thanks for replying akonsu. Could you please share any sample code or instructions/steps explaining the authorization process? I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: what software do you run on your server?

Comment: we are using LAMP environment for our server. Any other info you need akonsu?? Thanks again for replying back.

Comment: there is a help page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples My understanding is that all traffic from your app will go through your web server, not to twitter directly, and the server will need to authenticate the user and send requests to twitter on the user's behalf. during authentication, you will get an authorization URL from twitter, and will need to somehow display the web page at this URL to the user. I suppose you can open a browser from your app, but it will need to be in-process because if you just launch an external browser process, it won't work.

Comment: here is a thread on that: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205041-Twitter-OAuth